# Unable to retrieve a column value from different table in insert statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to retrieve column value from another table and inserting into another table but can't resolve it no error but unable to resolve it. Empty column appears. Trying to insert `t_vrm` in insert statement on `sql_fix_01` t_vrm is a `varchar` in SQL Server and its a vehicle registration number (number plate)

But returns empty column.

```
private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            tbl = new DataTable();
            tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ticket_reference", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
            tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ticket_number", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
            tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("t_vrm", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
            tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sql_fix_01", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
            tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sql_fix_02", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
            tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sql_fix_03", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
            tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sql_fix_04", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))); 

            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection();
            myConn.ConnectionString = stringConn;

            SqlCommand myComm = new SqlCommand();
            myComm.Connection = myConn;

            string[] tempArray = new string[this.textBox1.Lines.Length];
            tempArray = this.textBox1.Lines;

            if (this.textBox1.Lines.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            myConn.Open();
            int ticket_number = -666;
            string t_vrm = "";
            string sql_fix_01 = "";

            string stringDatetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
            //string stringDatetime = "20120829 17:00:00";

            for (int counter = 0; counter <= tempArray.Length - 1; counter++)
            {
                sql_fix_01 = "";

                t_vrm = "";
                ticket_number = -666;

                if (tempArray[counter].Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        myComm.CommandText = "SELECT t_number, t_vrm FROM tickets WHERE t_reference='" + tempArray[counter] + "'";
                        ticket_number = (int)myComm.ExecuteScalar();
                        t_vrm = (string)(myComm.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
```

MY ERROR IS IN THIS ROW.(**t_vrm**)

```
sql_fix_01 = "INSERT INTO [dvla] ([dvla_system_ref],[dvla_seq_no],[dvla_vrm],[dvla_due],[dvla_sent],[dvla_sent_by],[dvla_batch_no],[dvla_response_date],[dvla_query_destination]) VALUES(" + ticket_number.ToString().Trim() + ", 2 ,  t_vrm  , '" + stringDatetime + "', NULL,'',0, NULL, 'DVLATicketLetter');";
                    }
                    catch { }

                    if (ticket_number != -666)
                    {
                        tbl.Rows.Add(tempArray[counter], ticket_number,t_vrm, sql_fix_01, sql_fix_02, sql_fix_03, sql_fix_04);
                    }
                }
            }
            myConn.Close();

            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = tbl;
            this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

            DataView vwExport = new DataView(tbl);

            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (sfd.FileName != "")
                {
                    btnProcess.Enabled = false;
                    Application.DoEvents();

                    StreamWriter sw = null;
                    FileStream fs = null;

                    fs = File.Open(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                    sw = new StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

                    sw.WriteLine("USE ICPS");
                    sw.WriteLine("GO");
                    sw.WriteLine(" ");
                    sw.WriteLine("/* Set accounts Hold Status to ''VQ4 rescheduled'  */");
                    sw.WriteLine(" ");


                    foreach (DataRowView drv in vwExport)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("/* Ticket Reference:  " + drv["ticket_reference"].ToString() +  "/" + drv["ticket_number"].ToString() +  "/" + drv["t_vrm"].ToString() + "*/");
                        sw.WriteLine(drv["sql_fix_01"].ToString());
```

Comment: I don't want to be too picky, but...  You are prone to sql injection;

Comment: I have removed sql_fix_02. my probelm is with sql_fix_01 of t_vrm.

Comment: Have you checked by debugging whether t_vrm get's retrieved properly in the first place?

Comment: Yeah it retrieved fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with multiple values..

```
myComm.CommandText = "SELECT t_number, t_vrm 
          FROM tickets WHERE t_reference='" + tempArray[counter] + "'";

ticket_number = (int)myComm.ExecuteScalar();
t_vrm = (string)(myComm.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
```

You will need to use a [`DataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

```
SqlDataReader reader = myComm.ExecuteReader();

// Call Read before accessing data. 
while (reader.Read())
{
  ticket_number = reader.GetInt32(0);
  t_vrm = reader.GetString(1);
}
```

Also, to reiterate what **@Amber** said, look at [`Bobby Tables`](http://bobby-tables.com/), you really want to avoid `dynamic SQL`

Comment: so how can I retrieve t_vrm without using scalar.

Comment: Thanks christiandev. Its sorted now.

Comment: No problem.  btw, is that DVLA as in Drivers Vehicle Licensing Agency? if so, can you remove points from the database? (**joking obviously**) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Should'nt:

```
...VALUES(" + ticket_number.ToString().Trim() + ", 2 ,  t_vrm  , '" +...
```

Be:

```
...VALUES(" + ticket_number.ToString().Trim() + ", 2 , " + t_vrm + " , '" +...
```

Your `t_vrm` variable is part of the string.

Comment: I tried it but it still  empty in the column.It picks  t_number,and datatime but  not t_vrm.

Comment: That is because of what @christiandev answered below.